# Reordering Uniquely Ordered Models in ActiveRecord Association

Tags: validation, activerecord, model-associations

I have List model that has many items. Those items have a `priority` that is unique in the scope of the list.

```
class List < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :items
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :items
end

class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :priority, uniqueness: { :scope => :list_id }
end
```

So if I return a given list from an API call, it looks like this:

```
{
  items: [
    { "id": 1, "priority": 1 },
    { "id": 2, "priority": 2 },
    { "id": 3, "priority": 3 }
  ]
}
```

The user rearranges the items on the front-end and it makes a `PUT` request to the server

```
{
  items_attributes: [
    { "id": 1, "priority": 3 },
    { "id": 2, "priority": 1 },
    { "id": 3, "priority": 2 }
  ]
}
```

but this will fail. When one of these attempts to save, it will check if another item exists with the same list id and priority. Since the other item has not yet updated in the database, this validation will fail.

How can I achieve this update?

Answer (score 0):

Allow nils in the list_id column so you can reset the values.

```
validates :priority, uniqueness: { :scope => :list_id }, unless: Proc.new { |l| l.list_id.blank? }
```

In your controller, reset the column:

```
ItemController.update_all("priority = null");
```

Then set them using the passed params as you are now. Just make sure you test the validity of the model before you save (`valid?`).